# multiple transition not working (SCSS/CSS)

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass

How can I combine two transition to work at the same time on css3? I'm currently using compass.

Here is the code:

```
.team-member
{
    @include transition(color .25s linear, border .8s ease-in-out, border-color .8s ease-in-out);
    @include transition(color .25s linear, background-color .8s ease-in-out, background-color .8s ease-in-out);
    border-bottom: 6px solid $section-bg-color-default;
    background-color: $section-bg-color-default;    
}

.team-member:hover
{
    @include transition(color .25s linear, border .8s ease-in-out, border-color .8s ease-in-out);
    @include transition(color .25s linear, background-color .8s ease-in-out, background-color .8s ease-in-out);
    border-bottom: 6px solid $primary-accent-color;
    background-color: rgba(172,0,118,.08);
}
```

The background transition is working properly but the border does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitions, like any other `CSS` property, are overwritten by anything after them. So basically your `border` transition is being fully overwritten by the `background-color` transition. Just put them on the same line.

```
.team-member
{
    @include transition(color .25s linear, background-color .8s ease-in-out, background-color .8s ease-in-out, border .8s ease-in-out, border-color .8s ease-in-out);
    border-bottom: 6px solid $section-bg-color-default;
    background-color: $section-bg-color-default;    
}

.team-member:hover
{
    @include transition(color .25s linear, background-color .8s ease-in-out, background-color .8s ease-in-out, border .8s ease-in-out, border-color .8s ease-in-out);
    border-bottom: 6px solid $primary-accent-color;
    background-color: rgba(172,0,118,.08);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that information @Jnatalzia I did not thought that it could be combined in the same line.